# Request to add negative tags

Tags: feature-request

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to filter down my watched tags even further. I want to be able to choose some tags to NOT see at all.

For example:
`python` but without `pandas`.

The reason for this is that I have a fair bit of Python knowledge that I would like to share, but I find my feed constantly clogged up with data science or machine learning problems, of which I have little to no experience. This impacts my ability to help out as I'm fairly busy with my day job, and want to be able to quickly get an at a glance look of questions that are 100% relevant to my skillset.

I'm aware of some basic search functionality like `intags:` but this still can't achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Like this `[python] -[pandas]`? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+-%5Bpandas%5D&searchOn=3

Comment: @cigien oh my god, yes! Now I feel a bit like a clown for making this, I thought to myself StackExchange couldn't possibly not have this feature. I appreciate you.

Comment: Minor point: if you think some feature likely exists, as in this case, but you don't know how to use it, you should use the [support] tag instead.

Comment: @cigien Understandable, still learning the ropes. Apologies.

Comment: You can read the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) of SO for more advanced search tips, consider doing some more research first :D